# jQuery cloning too much?

Tags: jquery

This is probably a really easy concept I just misunderstand but taking this jsFiddle:

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

JS

```
var items = $('ul li').clone();

var cloner = $('ul').clone().addClass('before');

cloner.prependTo('nav');

items.appendTo('ul');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WZykS/3/

Why is the `ul` I clone have items 1,2,3,1,2,3... shouldn't it just be 1,2,3 ???

I'm trying to duplicate the current `ul` and add that duplicate before it then duplicating the items in that first list and duplicate the items within it but I end up with the items duplicated in both and I don't want that.

Comment: `$("ul")` will match every ul not only one.

Comment: It may be more useful to provide what is the expected input and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('ul').clone()` will clone the `<ul>` *and* all its children.  So, when you do `cloner.prependTo('nav')` you are adding the `<ul>` and its `<li>` to the DOM.

Then you do `items.appendTo('ul')`.  This appends the 3 `<li>`s that were cloned to *all* `<ul>`s on the page.

There is no need for `var items = $('ul li').clone()` or `items.appendTo('ul')`.

Comment: Hahaha... long day. I just realized that this is the problem. I didn't specify the appendTo to only the one I want, so it does it to both. Wow... that's embarrasing.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you *clone* the items. You never remove them from the dom. I think you are looking for [detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/). Detach also removes the elements from the dom.

This will also move all the li elements within your ul element. Remember however that this will target *all* ul elements on your page and move them to nav (make a more specific selector. Like an id or class).

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WZykS/4/)

```
$('ul').detach().appendTo('nav');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem.

```
items.appendTo('ul');
```

adds item 1,2,3 to both `<ul />` not just the first/last one.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are apending the items to both lists in the last line. The `ul` selector will match both lists.

If you swap the two last lines in the code, you will only add the items to the one list that exists at that time:

```
var items = $('ul li').clone();

var cloner = $('ul').clone().addClass('before');

items.appendTo('ul');

cloner.prependTo('nav');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/WZykS/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
// this creates a copy of each li
var items = $('ul li').clone();

// this clones the ul (and its children) and adds the class
var cloner = $('ul').clone().addClass('before');

// the cloned ul (with its children) are prepended to the nav element
cloner.prependTo('nav');

// the copied li are now appended to all found "ul" elements.
items.appendTo('ul');
```

The quickest way to do what you want is:

```
$('ul').clone().prepandTo('nav');
```

or if you really want to clear it out and add them in again:

```
$('ul').clone().empty().prependTo('nav');
$('li').clone().appendTo('ul:nth-child(1)');
```